# What do a couple of curly braces mean in gdb print command?

Tags: gdb

Debug messages from gdb:

```
(gdb) p head_->next
$43 = { 0x0 }

(gdb) p (void *)head_->next
$44 = (void *) 0x603014

(gdb) p / head_->next
$45 = { 0x0 }
```

Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

head_->next is a member variable declared like:

```
int *next[3];
```

At first, I thought head_->next was a pointer. But actually it's not. Now I'm confused, what does "{0x0}" mean in gdb?

Comment: Please don't put images where a simple text suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> head_->next is a member variable declared like:
>   `int *next[3];`

No, it's not. At least not in that file. If it were declared like that, you would see this:

```
(gdb) p head_->next
$1 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
```

Proof:

```
cat t.c
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Foo {
  int *next[3];
};

int main()
{
  struct Foo *head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Foo));
  return 0;
}

gcc -g t.c && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) start
(gdb) next
(gdb) p head->next
```

> what does "{0x0}" mean in gdb?

It means that GDB believes that the entity being printed is an array of 1 element.

If you want to examine 3 elements from that array, you can do this:

```
(gdb) p head_->next[0]@3
```

Comment: I checked that file and found it was "TYPE *next[1]", not "TYPE *next[3]". Everything is clear now. Thank you!